Can I know why my post was deleted by a bot?
My question Compiling a List of Schauder Bases for Function Spaces was deleted by a bot, I want to know why.

You got a comment pointing to the book Schauder Bases in Banach Spaces of Continuous Functions (LNM, volume 918) which certainly is not nothing. You can find a review here: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-11/issue-1/Review--Zbigniew-Semadeni-Schauder-bases-in-Banach-spaces-of/bams/1183551857.pdf

@DavidRoberts the link of that book in my question is corrupted

@ALIN I'm not entirely sure what you mean. However, I will point out that it would have helped the original question if you had shown some minimum homework, for instance doing some reference chasing from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis and including those in the question, or else just using a search engine to come up with papers eg https://www.google.com/search?q=schauder+basis+function+space which turns up https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/746095.pdf which is relevant. This is the kind of pre-question work that helps make your question more attractive to experts.

Many times I have started asking a question here, and in the process of doing the kind of literature checking that will make my question as good as I can get it, I answer my own question. This is actually a total win for MO, because it has helped me find the answer, and moreover I don't clog up the system when there are people with questions they really don't know how to answer (and that might be me at a different time!)

the question is now undeleted.

@ALIN Your question received 1 downvote and 0 upvotes. Unfortunately, your question was deleted based on the opinions of the members of a sample of size 1. With such a small sample size, one cannot take the deletion as an indicator that the community here likes or dislikes the question. We encourage (but do not require) the users on the main site to leave comments expressing their concerns about questions and answers instead of leaving unexplained downvotes.

@ALIN You appear to be a newish user to MO (though you do have additional content on other SE sites). Newer anonymous users would get better reception by first asking a few objective questions on the main site rather than softer open ended questions as you are getting acquainted with the community here. It may be a good idea to also answer questions on the main site to get a feel for how the culture of this site operates. Your question on the main site is actually three questions in one which is a hallmark of a softer question.

But your decision to ask a soft question as a newer user is your choice; I am simply stating what I think you should expect from the community here. Ideally, this site would be more welcoming to new users who demonstrate mathematical ability.

The official reason the software recorded for the auto-deletion is "Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions". You can read about this in the help centre. I believe your question satisfied the requirements:

the question is more than 30 days old, and ...

has −1 or lower score
has no answers
is not locked
has no active bounty


I can only recommend sticking around and reading more questions on related or semi-related topics that have a positive response from the community, to see how to best make use of MO. See also What topics can I ask about here?  in the help centre for more words of advice.
